# ioctl parameter size limit

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a kernel module that's involving ioctl operations on character devices. My driver accepts ioctl calls and I want to pass some data from kernel space to userspace. I'm having troubles with passing big data structures. I'm wondering if there's a way to solve this problem and somehow work around this restriction.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include "ioctl_def.h"

typedef struct
{
    char data[9999];
} DATA;

#define MAGIC 'v'
#define IOCTL_GET_DATA _IOR(MAGIC, 1, DATA)

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Noob");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Test module");
MODULE_VERSION("0.01");

#define MAJOR 400
#define NAME  "vdev"

static void __exit modexit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Modexit\n");
    unregister_chrdev(MAJOR, NAME);
}

static int dev_open( struct inode *n, struct file *f )
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Devopen\n");
    try_module_get(THIS_MODULE);
    return 0;
}

static int dev_release( struct inode *n, struct file *f )
{ 
    printk(KERN_INFO "Devrelease\n");
    module_put(THIS_MODULE);
    return 0;
}

static long dev_ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{ 
    printk("dev_ioctl cmd: %d\n", cmd);
    if((_IOC_TYPE(cmd) != MAGIC))
    {
        return -ENOTTY; 
    }

    switch(cmd)
    {
        case IOCTL_GET_DATA:
        {
            printk("IOCTL_GET_DATA: %d\n", cmd);
            DATA d;
            memset(&d, 0, sizeof(DATA));
            snprintf(d.data, sizeof(d.data), "%s", "Hello");            
            copy_to_user((void*)arg, &d, _IOC_SIZE(cmd));
        }
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}


static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offset)
{
    printk("input length: %d\n", count);
    char* data = kmalloc(count, GFP_KERNEL);
    memset(data, 0, count);

    if (copy_from_user(data + *offset, buf, (unsigned long)count))
    {
        printk("read error!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (data[count - 1] == 10) // ascii line feed dec = 10
        {
            data[count - 1] = 0;
        }
        printk("%s", data);
    }
    kfree(data);
    return count;
}

static const struct file_operations fops = { 
   .owner = THIS_MODULE, 
   .open = dev_open,
   .write = dev_write,
   .release = dev_release, 
 //  .read  = dev_read, 
   .unlocked_ioctl = dev_ioctl
};

static int __init modinit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Modinit\n");
    unregister_chrdev(MAJOR, NAME);

    int ret = register_chrdev(MAJOR, NAME, &fops);
    if( ret < 0 )
    { 
        printk(KERN_ERR "Could not register chardev\n" ); 
    }

    printk(KERN_ERR "Device initialized\n" );

    return ret;
}

module_init(modinit);
module_exit(modexit);
```

Current code compiles OKAY but the data size is not enough for my app in the user space. However whenever I increase the array to store more data e.g.

```
typedef struct
{
    char data[99999];
} DATA;
```

The code won't compile and the following error occurs:

```
vdev.c:54:3: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
   case IOCTL_GET_DATA:
   ^~~~
```

Comment: Why are you using _IOC_SIZE instead of the size of `d`?

Comment: I don't know for sure, just copy-pasted from somewhere else, though It returns the same size as size of d would

Comment: Passing the transfer size in the ioctl command code is just a convention, not an absolute rule. You could pass the size within the data itself as a prefix. Or you could pass a structure containing a pointer to the actual data and a length.

Comment: Also, it's not a good idea to create huge variables on the kernel stack, such as your `d` variable in the `IOCTL_GET_DATA` handler. The kernel stack has a fixed size and is pretty small!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter 'size' for an ioctl code is **limited** with (16K -1). You attempt to pass 'size' equal to 99999, which exceeds that limit.

The header file [include/uapi/asm-generic/ioctl.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.10/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/ioctl.h) contains following comment which explains origin of such limit:

```
/* ioctl command encoding: 32 bits total, command in lower 16 bits,
 * size of the parameter structure in the lower 14 bits of the
 * upper 16 bits.
 * Encoding the size of the parameter structure in the ioctl request
 * is useful for catching programs compiled with old versions
 * and to avoid overwriting user space outside the user buffer area.
 * The highest 2 bits are reserved for indicating the ``access mode''.
 * NOTE: This limits the max parameter size to 16kB -1 !
 */
```

---

There are many "standard" ways for pass data from the kernel to the user. E.g. it could be implemented as `.read` method of a character device, which naturally processes data of any length (including variable length).

One need to resort to `ioctl` only for "non-standard" cases, when other methods are not suited naturally, or have already used for other purposes.